# "who is going to do what"

Tags: grammar, usage

Can this phrase "who is going to do what" be used in English? For example can I say "The teacher wanted me to write down who is going to do what in the next week's class" or "The teacher wanted me to write down what student is going to do what in the next week's class"?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct:

> "The teacher wanted me to write down who is going to do what in the
>   next week's class"

This can be taken as a vague statement, as "who" could include everyone; like the Teacher and the subject doing the writing.

> "The teacher wanted me to write down what student is going to do what
>   in the next week's class"

This is more specific, as you have stated "what student", so we definitely know who you are talking about.  You could improve the specificity by expanding the second what statement.

Comment: Thanks. Based on the context, if I say "who" instead of "what student", I can  still be understood, right? I am talking about a situation where the teacher had me write the assignment topics of the students.

Comment: Yes, you will be understood.

The who, what, where, why, when - if most of those are in your statement, then you will be fine.

Comment: Note that ***what*** or ***which student*** explicitly includes the relevant noun which is normally only implicit. Exactly the same applies to *which student is going to do which/what **exercise** next week.*

Comment: Since I am writing down the assignments of the people in the class, not only one person's, isn't it better if I say "The teacher wanted me to write down who are(what students are) going to do what in the next week's class" instead of "The teacher wanted me to write down who(what student is) is going to do what in the next week's class"?

Comment: A classic (extremely un-PC) limerick goes, "A queer and a dyke in Khartoum/Decided to rent them a room./But they spent the whole night/In a terrible fight/As to who would what and to whom."

Comment: @Fire and Ice no. "Who" is singular in form here  and takes a singular verb, even when it in fact refers to many people. Hoever one says 'Who are the participants". Not fuly logical.